# catkin cmake error with ros (error code 1)

Tags: ros, catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I am following the tutorial here to create a workspace with catkin: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace
When I invoke catkin_make, I get this output:

```
ertugrul@Ertugrul-Laptop:~/ros/workspace/tutorial$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial
Source space: /home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/src
Build space: /home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/build
Devel space: /home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/devel
Install space: /home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/install
####
#### Running command: "cmake /home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/src -DCATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX=/home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/devel -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/install -G Unix Makefiles" in "/home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /home/ertugrul/anaconda2/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py", line 107, in <module>
    main()
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py", line 99, in main
    package = parse_package(args.package_xml)
  File "/home/ertugrul/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 317, in parse_package
    return parse_package_string(f.read(), filename)
  File "/home/ertugrul/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/catkin_pkg/package.py", line 450, in parse_package_string
    raise InvalidPackage('Error(s) in %s:%s' % (filename, ''.join(['\n- %s' % e for e in errors])))
catkin_pkg.package.InvalidPackage: Invalid package manifest "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml": Error(s) in /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml:
- The manifest must not contain the following tags: depend, build_export_depend, buildtool_export_depend
CMake Error at /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/safe_execute_process.cmake:11 (message):
  execute_process(/home/ertugrul/anaconda2/bin/python
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/parse_package_xml.py"
  "/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml"
  "/home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/build/catkin/catkin_generated/version/package.cmake")
  returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package_xml.cmake:63 (safe_execute_process)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/all.cmake:151 (_catkin_package_xml)
  /opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:20 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:52 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ertugrul/ros/workspace/tutorial/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
Invoking "cmake" failed
```

I have tried anything I could find online, but I'm now clueless. Thank you for any help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247794/catkin-cmake-error-with-ros-(error-code-1)/) by [dugrul](https://answers.ros.org/users/28498/dugrul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-11-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-11-11**:
Please include at least:

- which OS this is
- how you installed ROS (from sources, installed Debians)
- the exact commands you used to create your workspace
- the contents of `/opt/ros/kinetic/share/catkin/cmake/../package.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem using:

```
pip install -U rosdep rosinstall_generator wstool rosinstall six vcstools
```

---

Originally posted by [Horse-man](https://answers.ros.org/users/22198/horse-man/) with karma: 229 on 2017-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2017-08-17**:
To avoid others to blindly copy-n-paste your approach: you should only install ROS Python packages using `pip` on systems which don't have Debian packages. On Debian systems you should use `apt` to update the installed binary packages.

**Comment by [Cabbage](https://answers.ros.org/users/32159/cabbage/) on 2017-10-06**:
It works for me.
And also, my python path need to designate, we can use -t for pip:
pip install -t /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/  'your package'

**Comment by [Nebula](https://answers.ros.org/users/33043/nebula/) on 2018-02-02**:
It also worked for me I was getting similar error.

**Comment by [one-blue](https://answers.ros.org/users/51904/one-blue/) on 2020-02-19**:
I'm having the same problem above too,but it doesn't work when I try the way above.I'm using ros2.